# Categorizing users

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

Is there any way to categorize users in Drupal 7 so that one can browse users through a category (like users under "Seller" or "Buyer")?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a taxonomy vocabulary, lets say 'User category'. Add the different categories.
 
Then, go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields and add a field with term reference to the 'User category' vocabulary. It depends on the case but you could set this as a required field in order to force users to set a category.
Then create a view of type 'Users'. Be sure to set format as a table and in the table settings field set the fields as sortable. Also add an exposed filter to filter only on buyers or sellers. 
You can create a block of the view to show on the dashboard etc.

Comment: but it has a problem, if i do so and open the category then it say that "There is currently no content classified with this term." and there is no users under that category. Any idea?

Comment: A user entity isn't content so therefor it will not display the related users. Use http://drupal.org/project/views to handle the view.

Comment: so can i do as I've mentioned above?

Comment: you can create a block view with contextual filters and display the block only on taxonnomy pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you want to give different permitions to different usergroups. Therefore you're better off with creating different roles and put the users into the appropriate roles.

Every role has its own set of permitions.

1. Go to `admin/people/permissions/roles` and add the roles you need (seller, buyer).
2. Go to the user edit page and choose the roles it should have. You can assign a user to more than one role.

Comment: can you refer me any articles..cause i am a newbie

Comment: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/user

Comment: it is not an auto process